# how can create image hotspots to display images on hover effect?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I would like to create image hotspots on my rails app where a popup screen displays another image during hover as you can see below.

With your support I will try to write my code and/or use a third party module (ie. jquery based module etc) for some part. I want to figure out:

1. How to put overlay bluedots based on x/y coordinates?
2. How to trigger popup based secondary image window?

I will appreciate if you can provide code snippets and guidelines for this purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the `mousemove` event of your large and check whether the coordinates are inside the hotspot areas. Depending on how the hotspots are defined this is more or less complicated. For circles you will just have to check the distance from the center and compare it to the radius of course.

If the check succeeds and the image for the given hotspot is not currently displayed, you can add it to the document or display it, if it is already there but hidden.

The implementation details vary depending on what tools you use and the exact environment.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is the `<area>` tag, which defines geomtrical hotspots on an image. you can then use `ononmouseenter` and `onmouseexit` to show an image.

Read more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area

Example code from MDN uses circles, can use a rectangle or any polygon as well

```
<map name="primary">
  <area shape="circle" coords="75,75,75" href="left.html" alt="Click to go Left">
  <area shape="circle" coords="275,75,75" href="right.html" alt="Click to go Right">
</map>
<img usemap="#primary" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="350 x 150 pic">
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Would you please guide me how I can put "blue dots" on the image as well?